# Adding connection to LINQPad gives Unity.ResolutionFailedException

Tags: c#, ioc-container, dbcontext, linqpad

I'm trying to create a simple C# Program in LINQPad to test some DbContext stuff. I set up the connection to my DataModels Assembly and config file. However, when trying to run the program I receive this message:

> ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Clark.Logging.ILogger", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> ### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Clark.Logging.ILogger, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Clark.Logging.ILogger,(none)

So far, the program is simply:

```
void Main()
{
    var testString = "Testing";
    testString.Dump();

    // More code to eventually go here, which will use the connection and context.
}
```

This works if I do not select my connection.

I believe that the DataModel assembly uses Unity IoC for a custom logging setup. For some reason just associating this LINQPad file to the connection causes the error.

I may need to provide more information here, but what can I do to use my connection?

Comment: It looks like the DataContext library that you are using for your EF connection properties depends on another library that you have not referenced, or that, when it is used in your main project, there are other bindings that aren't part of the DataContext library that are required to satisfy (at least one of) its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't find a map, it will try to construct the type. In your case it fails since you cannot construct an interface.

With Unity, you can do it either by configuration using:

`container.RegisterType<InterfaceType, ConcreteType>();`

## Update#

Kindly try below and see, if this helps.

```
void Main()
{
  ILogger log = new Logger();   
  var source = new Subject<int>();
  source.Log(log, "Sample")
      .Subscribe();

  source.OnNext(1);
  source.OnCompleted();
}
```

Broadcasts a log entry for any of the configured listener/appender instances to write if appropriate

1. The log level
2. The message to log
3. An optional Exception instance to be associated with the log. Useful for capturing stack traces.

   public interface ILogger
   {
       void Write(LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception);
   }
   public class Logger : ILogger
   {
       public void Write(LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception)
           {
                   message.Dump(level.ToString());
           }
   }

   public enum LogLevel
   {
     /// 
     /// The lowest level, for any information that is considered verbose.
     /// 
     Verbose,
     /// 
     /// The second lowest level, for tracing the workflow in detail logging.
     /// 
     Trace,
     /// 
     /// For logging information that may help debugging problems.
     /// 
     Debug,
     /// 
     /// A non-critical error has occurred that will not interrupt the application but may degrade the user experience.
     /// 
     Warn,
     /// 
     /// For interesting business or technical actions such as a process starting or a request being made.
     /// 
     Info,
     /// 
     /// For errors that need immediate attention.
     /// 
     Error,
     /// 
     /// For catastrophic failures.
     /// 
     Fatal
   }

Extensions methods to the  interface.

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Fatal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Fatal(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Fatal, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Fatal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Fatal(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Fatal(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Error(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Error(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Error(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Info.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Info(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Info, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Info.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Info(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Info(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Warn.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Warn(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Warn, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Warn.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Warn(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Warn(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Debug.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Debug(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Debug, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message as Debug.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Debug(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Debug(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Trace, the second lowest level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Trace(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Trace, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message as Trace, the second lowest level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Trace(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Trace(null, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with an exception as Verbose, the lowest level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The related <see cref="Exception"/> for the message</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Verbose(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var formattedMessage = Format(format, args);
        logger.Write(LogLevel.Verbose, formattedMessage, exception);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message as Verbose, the lowest level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="format">The message as a string format</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments for the message</param>
    //[StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void Verbose(this ILogger logger, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        logger.Verbose(null, format, args);
    }

    private static string Format(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            return format;
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, format, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the entry to a method as a string like "MyType.MyMethod(1, ABC)". 
    /// Ensure the method being logged is not in-lined by the compiler/jitter with the
    /// [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">The instance of a logger to log with</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments passed to the method</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The <see cref="MethodEntry"/> logging method is useful for logging that a method has 
    /// been entered and also capturing the arguments of the method in the log.
    /// <example>
    /// In this example we log a method entry and the arguments.
    /// <code>
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    /// public void MyLoggedMethod(string s, DateTime dateTime)
    /// {
    ///     _logger.MethodEntry(s, dateTime);
    ///     //Method body goes here...
    /// }
    /// 
    /// ]]>
    /// </code>
    /// The output may look something like this
    /// 2012-01-31 12:00 [UI] DEBUG MyLoggedType.MyLoggedMethod(A, 31/12/2001 13:45:27)
    /// </example>
    /// </remarks>
    public static void MethodEntry(this ILogger logger, params object[] args)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var method = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
        var type = method.DeclaringType;
        var typeName = string.Empty;
        if (type != null) typeName = type.Name;
        string parenth = "()";
        var parameterDefinitions = method.GetParameters();
        if (parameterDefinitions.Length > 0)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                parenth = "(...)";
            }
            else
            {
                var values = string.Join(", ", args);
                parenth = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "({0})", values);
            }
        }

        logger.Debug("{0}.{1}{2}", typeName, method.Name, parenth);
    }

    public static IObservable<T> Log<T>(this IObservable<T> source, ILogger logger, string name)
    {
        return Observable.Using(
            () => logger.Time(name),
            timer => Observable.Create<T>(
                o =>
                {
                    logger.Trace("{0}.Subscribe()", name);
                    var subscription = source
                        .Do(
                            i => logger.Trace("{0}.OnNext({1})", name, i),
                            ex => logger.Trace("{0}.OnError({1})", name, ex),
                            () => logger.Trace("{0}.OnCompleted()", name))
                        .Subscribe(o);
                    var disposal = Disposable.Create(() => logger.Trace("{0}.Dispose()", name));
                    return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, disposal);
                })
            );
    }

    public static IDisposable Time(this ILogger logger, string name)
    {
        return new Timer(logger, name);
    }

    private sealed class Timer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly string _name;
        private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;

        public Timer(ILogger logger, string name)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _name = name;
            _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            _logger.Debug("{0} took {1}", _name, _stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my code I do something like `var multiLogger = new MultiLogger(); IoCHelper.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(multiLogger);`. But just adding that to my `Main()` in LINQPad doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Editing with sample code which you can try in LinqPad

Comment: I receive `CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Logger' could not be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)`. Trying to use log4net interferes with our custom logging class.

Comment: Press F4 and add the below references,

`System
 System.Reactive
 System.Reactive.Concurrency
 System.Reactive.Disposables
 System.Reactive.Joins
 System.Reactive.Linq
 System.Reactive.Subjects
 System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks
 System.Windows.Forms
 System.Globalization`

Comment: I'm not sure how that will help me. The original code that uses this DbContext does not use Reactive.

Comment: It's a sample related to your posted issue logger. Is it possible to share your code snippet of linqpad that throws up the error. So that I can check and provide the info.

Comment: As I mentioned, the above code is ALL that is in LINQPad. I do not get the error until I 'connect' to the DbContext and config file. I do not know what part of the DbContext is causing the error.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen that. I've connected to DbContexts before. It's more complicated than that. This doesn't seem to be something you're familiar with.

Comment: @MKenyonII : As you have said I do not know what part of the DbContext is causing the error.

Without sharing any info of source we cant get you the answer. And we can give the sample solution to follow. If you find the solution please post, so we can learn from that and see what i am missing.